# How to smartly match two data frames using Python (using pandas or other means)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I have one pandas dataframe composed of the names of the world's cities as well as countries, to which cities belong,

```
city.head(3)

    city    country
0   Qal eh-ye Now   Afghanistan
1   Chaghcharan Afghanistan
2   Lashkar Gah Afghanistan
```

and another data frame consisting of addresses of the world's universities, which is shown below:

```
df.head(3)
    university
0   Inst Huizhou, Huihzhou 516001, Guangdong, Peop...
1   Guangxi Acad Sci, Nanning 530004, Guangxi, Peo...
2   Shenzhen VisuCA Key Lab SIAT, Shenzhen, People...
```

The locations of cities' names are irregularly distributed across rows. I would like to match the city names with the addresses of world's universities. That is, I would like to know which city each university is located in. Hopefully, the city name matched is shown in the same row as the address of each university.

I've tried the following, and it doesn't work because the locations of cities are irregular across the rows.

```
df['university'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Comment: @fffchao You are welcome. Now it would be great if you show what have you tried to solve this task.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `apply`

```
city_list = city.tolist()

def match_city(row):
    for city in city_list:
        if city in row['university']: return city
    return 'None'

df['city'] = df.apply(match_city, axis=1)
```

I assume the addresses of university data is clean enough. If you want to do more advanced checking of matching, you can adjust the `match_city` function.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. However, how to prevent partial match? For instance, the address of "New York" is matched as York. Since the city series is actually from a dataframe including countries, to which cities belong, is it possible to match taking into account the information of countries?

Comment: Your example suggests that your adress data is cleanly separated by commas. You just need an additional step where you take the strings in the list that `tolist()` returns and separate them again at each comma. You then get a list of lists, and one of the elements in each sublist should be your correct city name. With this you also have your country names cleanly separated in your sublists to use for matching.

Answer (score 2):

In order to deal with the inconsistent structure of your strings, a good solution is to use regular expressions. I mocked up some data based on your description and created a function to capture the city from the strings.

In my solution I used numpy to output NaN values when there wasn't a match, but you could easily just make it a blank string. I also included a test case where the input was blank in order to display the NaN result.

```
import re
import numpy as np

data = ["Inst Huizhou, Huihzhou 516001, Guangdong, People's Republic of China",
        "Guangxi Acad Sci, Nanning 530004, Guangxi, People's Republic of China",
        "Shenzhen VisuCA Key Lab SIAT, Shenzhen, People's Republic of China",
        "New York University, New York, New York 10012, United States of America",
        ""]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['university'])

def extract_city(row):
    match = re.match('^[^,]*,([^,]*),', row)
    if match:
        city = re.sub('\d+', '', match.group(1)).strip()
    else:
        city = np.nan
    return city


df.university.apply(extract_city)
```

Here's the output:

```
0    Huihzhou
1     Nanning
2    Shenzhen
3    New York
4         NaN
Name: university, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Some addresses are really messy, so that the matched results are not cities. For instance, for the address "'Guizhou Acad Sci, Guizhou Inst Biol, Guiyang 550009, Guizhou, P", the matched result is "Guizhou Inst Biol", but "Guiyang" is the city name. There  are some other similar issues.

Comment: You should really try to include all of the edge cases that you're having problems with in the prompt. There have been two good solutions based on your original question, but you've added details to both that make our solutions incomplete. Better yet, just include a link to the data that you're using.

Comment: sorry for updating the original question, which is my first question here. The partial data of university addresses is located at the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxnx3h22yvi49c1/sample_univ_address.xlsx?dl=0.  Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like there isn't a perfect solution for your data, but you might try using a combination of regular expressions and/or string replacement (like in my answer) along with the clever word mapping in @Svend's answer. In looking at the sample data I found specific replacement patterns you could use for certain countries, but without all of the data it's pretty difficult to give you a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that after a few pre-processing that reduce address into city level information (we don't need to be exact, but try your best; like removing numbers etc), and then merge the dataframes based on text similarities.

You may consider text similarity measures like levenshtein distance or jaro-winkler which are commonly used to match the words.

Here is example for text similarity:

```
class DLDistance:
    def __init__(self, s1): 
        self.s1 = s1
        self.d = {}
        self.lenstr1 = len(self.s1)     
        for i in xrange(-1,self.lenstr1+1):
            self.d[(i,-1)] = i+1

    def distance(self, s2):
        lenstr2 = len(s2)
        for j in xrange(-1,lenstr2+1):
            self.d[(-1,j)] = j+1

        for i in xrange(self.lenstr1):
            for j in xrange(lenstr2):
                if self.s1[i] == s2[j]:
                    cost = 0
                else:
                    cost = 1
                self.d[(i,j)] = min(
                               self.d[(i-1,j)] + 1, # deletion
                               self.d[(i,j-1)] + 1, # insertion
                               self.d[(i-1,j-1)] + cost, # substitution
                              )
                if i and j and self.s1[i]==s2[j-1] and self.s1[i-1] == s2[j]:
                    self.d[(i,j)] = min (self.d[(i,j)], self.d[i-2,j-2] + cost) # transposition

        return self.d[self.lenstr1-1,lenstr2-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
   base = u'abs'
   cmpstrs = [u'abs', u'sdfbasz', u'asdf', u'hfghfg']
   dl = DLDistance(base)

   for s in cmpstrs:
      print "damerau_levenshtein"
      print dl.distance(s)
```

Even though, it has high level of computation complexity since it calculate N*M times of distance measure where N rows in the first dataframe, M rows in the second dataframe.(To reduce computatinal complexity, you can truncate the set who needs comparison by only comparing the rows which have the same first character)

levenshtein distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

jaro-winkler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance

Answer (score 1):

I think one simple idea would be to create a mapping from any word or sequence of word of any address to the full address the word is part of, with the assumption that one of those address words is the cites. In a second step we match this with the set of known cities that you have, and anything that is not a known city gets discarded.

A mapping from each single word to address is as simple as:

```
def address_to_dict(address):
    return {word: address for word in address.split(",")}
```

And we can easily extend this to include the set of bi-grams, tri-gram,... so that universities encoded in several words are also collected. See a discussion here: [Elegant N-gram Generation in Python](http://locallyoptimal.com/blog/2013/01/20/elegant-n-gram-generation-in-python/)

We can then apply this to every address we have to obtain one grand mapping from any word to the full address:

```
word_to_address_mapping = pd.DataFrame(df.university.apply(address_to_dict ).tolist()).stack()

word_to_address_mapping = pd.DataFrame(word_to_address_mapping, 
                                       columns=["address"])
word_to_address_mapping.index = word_to_address_mapping.index.droplevel(level=0)
word_to_address_mapping
```

This yields something like this:

[image]

All you have to do then is join this with the actual city list you have: this will automatically discard any entry in `word_to_address_mapping` which is not a known city, and provide a mapping between university address and their city.

```
# the outer join here should ensure that several university in the 
# same city do not overwrite each other
pd.merge(left=word_to_address_mapping, right=city,
         left_index=True, right_on="city", 
         how="outer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial match is prevented in the below function. Information of countries also considered while matching cities. To use this function university dataframe need to be split into list data type, such that every piece of address split into list of strings.

```
In [22]: def get_city(univ_name_split):
   ....:     # find country from university address
   ....:     for name in univ_name_split:
   ....:         if name in city['country'].values:
   ....:             country = name
   ....:     else:
   ....:         country = None

   ....:     if country:
   ....:         cities = city[city.country == country].city.values
   ....:     else:
   ....:         cities = city['city'].values

   ....:     # find city from university address
   ....:     for name in univ_name_split:
   ....:         if name in cities:
   ....:             return name
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return None
   ....:     


In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: city = pd.read_csv('city.csv')

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('university.csv')

In [4]: # splitting university name and address

In [5]: df_split = df['university'].str.split(',')

In [6]: df_split = df_split.apply(lambda x:[i.strip() for i in x])

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
                                          university
0  Kongu Engineering College, Perundurai, Erode, ...
1           Anna University - Guindy, Chennai, India
2  Birla Institute of Technology and Science, Pil...

In [11]: df_split
Out[11]: 
0    [Kongu Engineering College, Perundurai, Erode,...
1           [Anna University - Guindy, Chennai, India]
2    [Birla Institute of Technology and Science, Pi...
Name: university, dtype: object

In [12]: city
Out[12]: 
         city country
0   Bangalore   India
1     Chennai   India
2  Coimbatore   India
3       Delhi   India
4       Erode   India


#This function is shorter version of above function
In [14]: def get_city(univ_name_split):
   ....:     for name in univ_name_split:
   ....:         if name in city['city'].values:
   ....:             return name
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return None
   ....:     

In [15]: df['city'] = df_split.apply(get_city)

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
                                          university     city
0  Kongu Engineering College, Perundurai, Erode, ...    Erode
1           Anna University - Guindy, Chennai, India  Chennai
2  Birla Institute of Technology and Science, Pil...     None
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tiny library for my projects, especially for fuzzy joins. It might not be the fastest solution but it may help, feel free to use.
[Link to my GitHub repo](https://github.com/ddaskan/customLibraries/blob/master/analysis_pack.py)